# Is "de.mynodejs.net" a trojaner?

Tags: node.js, malware

I am a full-stack developer but since I installed my  new antivirus program
(malwarebytes) I receive always the following nodification (see image below).
I work a lot with node.js (REACT, REACT-Native) therefore I am unsure if that is a virus.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is.

They provide a JS function convince Windows Defender
not to report back on files.